# How to comment class for code completion in phpstorm

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpdoc

Suppose I have a class

```
class Class1
{
    public function method1(){
        return "hello world";
    }

}
```

and I have another class that uses this in a class

```
class Class2
{
     /** @var $firstClass Class1 */
     private $firstClass;

     public function __construct($firstClass)
     {
            $this->firstClass = $firstClass;

     }

     public function method2()
     {
            return $this->firstClass-> "I want code completion to work here"
     }
 }
```

How do I get the code completion to work using PHPDoc. I've searched phpdoc for scope, declaration, all kinds of stuff. I can't figure out the terms or placement of the comment line for phpdoc to pick this up.

I'm using phpstorm. Help!

Comment: Your example works just fine (checked in both v6.0.3 and v7 EAP build). Possibly your real code differs from the example. BTW -- there is no need for variable name when writing PHPDoc comment for class variable/field (since such PHPDoc comment **must** be placed just before that field), this should be enough: `/** @var Class1 */  private $firstClass;`

Comment: I had instead to manually add the variable name in PHPDoc comment, otherwise I did not get autocompletion.
For example like this (without adding `$newUser`, autocompletion does not work). `/** @var $newUser \Model\User */`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Check your class namespaces.**

If class have namespace be sure you properly define them in comments or by alias.
*Comments example:*

```
...
    /** @var \vendor\namespace\Class1 */
    private $firstClass;
...
```

*Alias example:*

```
use \vendor\namespace\Class1;
...
    /** @var Class1 */
    private $firstClass;
...
```

**Check project directories definition.**

If your class directories not defined in project settings, PHPStorm can't index those classes. In this case code completion will not work. How to [set up project directories in PHPStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/configuring-project-structure.html).

**Clear PHPStorm cache.**

Sometimes PHPStorm cache became invalid. Because of this, codecompletion may not work properly. [Official how to cache cleanup](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/cleaning-system-cache.html).